# Using Google Apps Script API to access another user

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api

I'm really confused with this. I want to use the Gmail API to access and send mail in another account using google apps script. I have enabled Gmail in the Advanced Google Services and have enabled the API on the console. The following code works when I use a value of 'me' but when I try it for another user I get a 'Delegation denied' error. I fully understand that I can't just put in whatever email address I want and expect to be able to access it, but I can't seem to find/understand the documentation that lays out the steps to allow this to work.

```
function listLabels() {
  var response = Gmail.Users.Labels.list('user@example.com');
  Logger.log("Labels:");
  for (var i = 0; i < response.labels.length; i++) {
     var label = response.labels[i];
     Logger.log("- %s", label.name);
  }
}
```

Comment: you cant use delegation from apps script as apps script doesnt support using service accounts. you would need to make an oauth2 flow and have that user authorize.

Comment: On top of what @ZigMandel said: unless this is a google domains or google for work account to my knowledge you cant use service accounts with gmail.  you need to use Oauth2.

Comment: On the flip side if this IS a google work/edu/gov domain and you can register a service account that is associated with your script through the domain admin console to access domain users resources.

Comment: @DalmTo It is a google apps account but I need it to work across other domains. To rephrase it, other users have a filter setup which moves particular emails to a queue label, the script picks these up and allocates to another label depending on the result. It will need to apply the same label in my mail so I can monitor it. It was easy enough to do for myself but becomes much harder to do for others. Does oauth2 allow this and is it a nightmare to try and implement?

Comment: This is possible, but not a simple setup. You would build a script (I'd assume a webapp) that runs as the user. The user would have to login in, authorize it and perform your business logic. You then could have your credentials saved in the script properties. These credentials would be protected from eveyone who does not have editor rights to the script.    Using these credentials you can make your calls to the Gmail API to manipulate your account.